# How to retrieve elements from a mapping to an array of structs

Tags: solidity-0.5.x, truffle-console

I have recently started playing around with SmartContracts and I have run into a problem which I can not find a solution to.

I have the following struct and mapping in my Smart Contract:

```
struct Object{
    string objId;
    uint256 rank;
}

mapping(address => Object[]) public userObjects;
```

Using the truffle console I'm trying to retrieve the objects within the **userObjects** in the mapping like so:

```
truffle(development)> object = myContract.userObjects(accounts[0], 0)

truffle(development)> object
Result { '0': '1', '1': <BN: a>, objId: '1', rank: <BN: a> }
```

Looking at the Result I can see that the **objId** and the **rank** are correct. Now I would like to access these fields but I cannot figure out how I can do that. I have tried the following:

```
truffle(development)> object.objId
undefined
truffle(development)> object.rank
undefined
```

Am I referencing the attributes incorrectly? 
Is it possible to do that in the first place?

I am using truffle version 5.0.32

Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what I was doing wrong.
The problem was with the assignment of **object**:

Instead of:

```
truffle(development)> object = myContract.userObjects(accounts[0], 0)
```

I was supposed to assign the object asynchronously

```
truffle(development)> object = await myContract.userObjects(accounts[0], 0)
truffle(development)> object.postId
'1'
```

Even though async-await makes it possible for me to access **object.postId**, I still don't get why it didnt work before as object was correctly assigned earlier as well. But anyways my retrieval problem is now solved.